# Better way to minimize the code

Tags: c#

Is there an easier way to set properties based on boolean values?

```
if(a)
{
    if(b)
        foreach(var item in items)
            item.B = B;
    else if(c)
        foreach(var item in items)
            item.C = C;
    /*...*/
    else if(e)
        foreach(var item in items)
            item.E = E;
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. And without nowing your check condition variables, it doesnt make sense to make comment.

Comment: thus the indentation seems out of the place => misunderstanding the branching structure

Comment: Just use brackets. It makes it harder to make breaking changes to the code.

Comment: The answer is no... No within the context of your question. We all assume a, b, c, d are Booleans but have absolutely no context to the question.

Comment: If `a`, `b` and `c` are all very different conditions, then it's very hard to shorten.

Comment: You can use reflection to access and set property values but without more information on those lower case booleans, it's hard to tell if such an option would work.

Comment: How long is a piece of string is what you just asked. there is not context here and as such you could make this code look different heaps of ways yet as it stands none of it will help you as we have no context

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
if (!a) return;
B = b ? "some value" : null;
C = c ? "some value" : null;
E = e ? "some value" : null;
items.ToList().ForEach(u =>
{
  u.B = B;
  u.C = C;
  u.E = E;
});
```

Basically you have to update only when a is true.
Hence when a is false, just return(assuming this is in a void method)

Now, if b is false, the item.B will not be updated. Considering it as a string, even if you do not update it, it will still be null. Precisely, update B,C and E based on your flags and then use ".ForEach" to update it directly.

Note: You will have to refactor the code in terms of updating B,C and E based on your data types and the calling method